# C++ How to check the type of a variant map at compile time

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, variant

I would like to have a map of key, value pairs; the keys can be implemented as string or enum class; but the values need to support multiple types, e.g. `int` or `bool`

Now, I would want to have a function with the following signature

```
template<typename T>
void getOption(KeyClass key_, T& value_)
```

Given that the map will be constant, is it possible to make the function checking the type at compile time?

For example, if the map is something like {"start_time": 2, "can_abort": false}

There should be a compilation error on

```
bool can_abort;
getOption("start_time", can_abort);
```

Comment: It looks like you may use `tuple` with item index acting as a key.

Comment: Can you provide some example code where this is useful? As well as a [mcve] of what you are having trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use enum values for your keys, and the types and values are known at compile-time, why not just have a plain struct?

```
struct options_t {
    int start_time;
    bool can_abort;
};
```

If you really must iterate over elements of different types, you can go full voodoo and use Louis Dionne's Boost.Hana library. It has a [multi-type map class](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/hana/doc/html/structboost_1_1hana_1_1map.html). Everything will be checked at compile time.

Alternatively, if you want more run-time-oriented behavior, and you want flexibility w.r.t. the types you stick in your map, you could use type erasure and make it, say, an `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::any>`. The [`std::any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) type holds, well, a value of any type; but it is up to you to know which type to try and extract from it (if you're wrong you get an exception) - i.e. you won't have compile time checking.

As for using a variant - you can use those, but if your keys are `std::string`s, then nothing is going to be checked at compile time, as `std::string`s involve heap allocation.

Comment: @SombreroChicken: You are [greatly misinformed](https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get), my friend... thank Antony Polukhin for that.

Comment: That takes away any chance of humor. It's like explaining the joke.